# jquery - return number of children but for different parent element

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-selectors

I have this issue where .length from the jquery syntax does not return me the proper number of child elements.

My code is smtg like this.

```
<div class="swiper-container swiper1">
    <div class="swiper-wrapper">
        <div class="swiper-slide">item1</div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">item2</div>
        ...
        <div class="swiper-slide">
            <div class="swiper-container swiper-v">
                <div class="swiper-wrapper">
                    <div class="swiper-slide">item1</div>
                    <div class="swiper-slide">item2</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now what happens here is that when I use jquery to return the number of child elements of both swiper it gives me an incorrect value.

For example

```
alert($('.swiper1 .swiper-slide').length); // which returns me 11
```

and

```
alert($('.swiper-v .swiper-slide').length); // which return me 2 - which is correct
```

Any idea?

P.S. I'm using the iDangero.us Mobile Swiper Plugin :)

Comment: I dont see any issue. here is the [jsfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/NETNU/).I got 9 and 2 as the lengths

Comment: What exactly is the problem you seem to face.. Can you give the complete HTML or a working fiddle to specify your problem..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
$('.swiper1 > .swiper-wrapper').children().length;
```

and

```
$('.swiper-v > .swiper-wrapper').children().length;
```

Test on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HxJAb/)

Comment: That always returns 1 here, while the OP says 2 is correct for the second snippet.

Comment: I need the number of child elements in the wrapper class not the container class.

Comment: Thanks Talha i love youuuuuuuuuuuuu :D

Answer (score 0):

I actually dont see an issue here. Check this [jsfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/NETNU/1/).

Comment: Hi, I've made a mistake with the code placement. the second slider is actually suppose to be an item amongst the other items from the first slider. I edited the code so can you look at it again? Thanks again.

Comment: I dont understand, what is your question? for this case you will get lengths 12 and 2 which are the expected lengths. check [here](http://jsfiddle.net/NETNU/2/)

Comment: The thing is the first slider is to return 9 which indicates the number of pages the page has. Whereas the second slider acts like a content slider for posts. In the case where the first slider returns 11 will be incorrect as it will generate 11 navigational buttons which is suppose to be 9 only.